# Beanstream::InternalServerException: on rails 4.2 using gem "beanstream"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, beanstream

Hey I am facing this error:
[image: Beanstream Internal Server Exception]

I am using gem "beanstream" have configured the Beanstream initializer as well

```
Beanstream.profiles_api_key = ENV['beanstream_profiles_api_key']
Beanstream.merchant_id = ENV['beanstream_merchant_id']
Beanstream.payments_api_key = ENV['beanstream_payments_api_key']
```

Code to call the payments API:

```
@payments_api = Beanstream::PaymentsAPI.new
request = @payments_api.getPaymentRequestTemplate()
request[:payment_method] = 'payment_profile'
        request[:amount] = @amount
        request[:payment_profile] = {
          :customer_code => beanstream_customer_code,
          :card_id => 1,
          :complete => false
        }
beanstream_payment_params = request

@payments_api.make_payment(beanstream_payment_params)
```

Comment: I mean this gem looks pretty dodgy to start with, and then you're not providing any of the card details. Obviously, proving incomplete data should be handled a bit nicer, but 1.0 and weird gem so I can easily imagine it.